# split a data frame using after a date where the value of another variable reaches to max/min on that date

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, split

I have a dataset that is similar to the following:

```r
df <- data.frame( 
                date = c("2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06"),
               value = c(0,1,2,7,3,4))
```

I would like to split my data frame into two smaller data frames such that the first data frame includes a part of the original data frame before the value reaches its max (i.e. 7) and the second part of the data frame includes the rest of the original data frame as follows:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
                 date = c("2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03"),
                 value = c(0,1,2)
                 )
df2 <- data.frame(
                 date = c("2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06"),
                 value = c(7, 3, 4)
                 )
```

*** The 2nd part of the question
Now assume that I have the following dataset including more than one object identified by IDs. So, I would like to the same thing as explained above and applied to all objects (IDs)

```r
df <- data.frame( ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                date = c("2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02","2020-02-03", "2020-02-04"),
               value = c(0,1,2,7,3,4,10,16,11,12))
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which.max` to get the index of `max` value and use it to subset the dataframe.

```
ind <- which.max(df$value)
df1 <- df[seq_len(ind - 1), ]
df2 <- df[ind:nrow(df), ]

df1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  date       value
#  <chr>      <dbl>
#1 2020-02-01     0
#2 2020-02-02     1
#3 2020-02-03     2

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  date       value
#  <chr>      <dbl>
#1 2020-02-04     7
#2 2020-02-05     3
#3 2020-02-06     4
```

---

We could create a list of dataframes if there are lot of `ID`'s and we have to do this for each `ID`.

```
result <- df %>%
            group_split(ID) %>%
            purrr::map(~{.x %>% 
               group_split(row_number() < which.max(value), .keep = FALSE)})

## In case, someone is interested you could make a data frame from the list above as follows: 
result_df <- result %>%
bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to apply this to a larger dataset including objects with different ids. I mean using something like nest and map together.

Comment: @SeyedHosseini Please update your example accordingly and show the expected output for it. Also make sure your example actually runs. For example, using `as_tibble` returns an error for me, I had to change it to `tibble`.

Comment: Thank you @ronak-shah, following your instruction I edited the question. Appreciate your time and advice.

Comment: Check updated answer. It is better to create list of dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using base R:

```
> df
        date value
1 2020-02-01     0
2 2020-02-02     1
3 2020-02-03     2
4 2020-02-04     7
5 2020-02-05     3
6 2020-02-06     4
> df1 <-  df[1:(which(df$value == max(df$value)) - 1), ]
> df2 <- df[which(df$value == max(df$value)):nrow(df), ]
> df1
        date value
1 2020-02-01     0
2 2020-02-02     1
3 2020-02-03     2
> df2
        date value
4 2020-02-04     7
5 2020-02-05     3
6 2020-02-06     4
>
```

For the grouped data:

```
> mylist <- df %>% split(f = df$ID)
> mylist
$`1`
  ID       date value
1  1 2020-02-01     0
2  1 2020-02-02     1
3  1 2020-02-03     2
4  1 2020-02-04     7
5  1 2020-02-05     3
6  1 2020-02-06     4

$`2`
   ID       date value
7   2 2020-02-01    10
8   2 2020-02-02    16
9   2 2020-02-03    11
10  2 2020-02-04    12

> split_list <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[1:(which.max(x$value) - 1),])
> split_list <- append(split_list, lapply(mylist, function(x) x[which.max(x$value): nrow(x),]))
> split_list
$`1`
  ID       date value
1  1 2020-02-01     0
2  1 2020-02-02     1
3  1 2020-02-03     2

$`2`
  ID       date value
7  2 2020-02-01    10

$`1`
  ID       date value
4  1 2020-02-04     7
5  1 2020-02-05     3
6  1 2020-02-06     4

$`2`
   ID       date value
8   2 2020-02-02    16
9   2 2020-02-03    11
10  2 2020-02-04    12

>
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to apply this to a larger dataset including objects with different ids. I mean using something like nest and map together

Comment: I'd assume if objects have IDs, we'd have to group them, but as Ronak mentioned, please share data that reflects yours so that solution can be arrived that addresses your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your response. I updated the question to clarify my point. Your time and advice are appreciated.

Comment: Have added the code for grouped data, please check if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time, as I am not really good at basic R, the answer by @ronak-shah works better for me.